# Getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable error when extending two sliced list

Tags: python, list, numpy-slicing

```
def rotLeft(a, d):
    rotate = a[:d]
    Remaining = a[d:]
    ar_rot=Remaining.extend(rotate)
    return ar_rot
```

I am getting this error for ar_rot variable . Why i am getting this error while extending two 
        sliced list ?TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: Since you're specifically asking about numpy, [please provide more complete code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reflects what numpy has to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because extend() return nothing. Try

```
def rotLeft(a, d):
    rotate = a[:d]
    Remaining = a[d:]
    Remaining.extend(rotate)
    return Remaining
```